# program a web browser textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

The textbox adds "http://" to what ever the users enters (Ex. "google.com" turns to "http://google.com") before sending to the web browser, but if the user enters "http://" before their website you get an error.

this is my code:

```
     private void bargo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri targetUri = new Uri(System.String.Format("http://{0}", bar.Text));
        web.Navigate(targetUri);

    }
```

Comment: so test for "http://" on the input and either remove it or do not add it. What was the question?

Comment: `if(!bar.Text.Contains("http://"))` ?

Comment: how do I get the text box to loose focus after go button is clicked

Comment: What makes you think you have to? What does that have to do with the code that you posted? Or any error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test whether bar.text already starts with http:// like this:

```
    private void bargo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = bar.Text;
        if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
        {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        web.Navigate(new Uri(url);
    }
```

If your user enters "https://" or "ftp://" (or  gopher://, irc://, ircs://, ftp://, news://, nntp://, worldwind://, telnet://, svn://, git://, mms:// and mailto:) this method will still add "http://" and fail.

A better solution would be to pass a string into web.Navigate() instead of a uri.  When you pass in a string, the WebBrowser control automatically adds http:// like a browser would.

```
    private void bargo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        web.Navigate(bar.Text);
    }
```

**EDIT:** For Windows Phone 7

```
    private void bargo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        web.NavigateToString(bar.Text);
    }
```

Comment: for some odd reason web.navigate(bar.text) doesn't work with windows phone.

Comment: I missed that you were using Windows Phone.  Try:
    web.NavigateToString(bar.Text);

Answer (score 0):

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
if (culture .IsPrefix(textbox.Text, "http://") == false)
    textbox.Text = "http://" + textbox.Text;
var regex = new Regex(@"^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$");
if (regex.IsMatch(textbox.Text))
{
   //Your logic here
}
```